# Server not finding files created on certain date

Tags: linux, tomcat

I'm getting this error on 4 `.svg` images when loading a page:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

There are about 15 other `.svg` images located in the same directory that the server is able to find using the same url pattern.

- The 4 images that it isn't able to find were created on April 9th
- the images that it can find were created on March 18.

All the files have the same permissions.

Below is an example of a file that can be found and one that cannot. Why would the date when the files were created prevent the server from finding files created on a certain date?

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 XXXa XXX  5040 Mar 18 08:26 brm-execution-server.svg
-rw-r--r-- 1 XXXa XXX  6662 Apr  9 09:55 brm-executions.svg
```

I'm having this issue using Linux and Tomcat 7, however I also have this same web application deployed locally on a Windows PC where Tomcat is able to find every resource.

Could this warning in the logs cause a problem like this?

```
SEVERE: The web application [/software-suite] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [com.sun.jersey.core.header.HttpDateFormat$1] (value [com.sun.jersey.core.header.HttpDateFormat$1@6d26116b]) and a value of type [java.util.Collections.UnmodifiableRandomAccessList] (value [[java.text.SimpleDateFormat@c4dc9900, java.text.SimpleDateFormat@b831d961, java.text.SimpleDateFormat@937457b6]]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
```

Comment: if you look at the output of `ls -lZ` are they in different SELinux contexts?

Comment: The ouput of that command looks like this                                                   -rw-r--r-- XXXa XXX ?                                brm-execution-server.svg  \n
-rw-r--r-- XXXa XXX ?                                brm-executions.svg

Comment: So `selinux` is not enabled for you given the `?`s.  Is Tomcat serving the static files or is another component used for that?

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the corresponding entry in the server
log files?

*Please don’t add the information as a comment. It’s much better to improve the quality of your question by editing it to include relevant information. Otherwise, it can get lost in the comments. Many users can make the time to read a question but not all the comments.*

Comment: Tomcat is serving the static files.  The log output for this web application is supposed to be redirected to a file but that file isn't being generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the image files actually weren't in the folder.  The server hosting the web application I'm maintaining has 2 folders with the same name containing the images used for the page.  The url is transformed and doesn't directly map to a file path on the server.  I discovered the other directory with the same name and these 4 images were missing, I copied them over from the other directory and the problem is resolved.